# Magento: Error between cleaning Cache and reindex

Tags: php, magento, caching

Since I updated Magento (from 1.4.2.0 to 1.7.0.2) I always get the following error *after* I cleaned the cache and *before* I reindex all:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:233:"Error in file: "/html/magento_update/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/sql/reports_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.0.0.1.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily' already exists";i:1;s:942:"#0 /html/magento_update/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /html/magento_update/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.0.0', '1.6.0.0.1')
#2 /html/magento_update/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.0.0', '1.6.0.0.1')
#3 /html/magento_update/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /html/magento_update/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /html/magento_update/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /html/magento_update/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /html/magento_update/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I use this code for cleaning the cache:

```
Mage::app()->cleanCache();
$enable = array();
foreach ( Mage::helper( 'core' )->getCacheTypes() as $type => $label ) {
    $enable[$type] = 1;
} 
Mage::app()->saveUseCache( $enable );
```

Because it's in the file "upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.0.0.1.php" ... maybe there went something wrong with the update? I did it via SSH, following different how-tos ... to get around the errors that occured.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by droping these three tables:

- report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily
- report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly
- report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly

... like suggested here: http://duntuk.com/magento-upgrade#comment-417. First I only truncated them, which was not enough.